# Asp.Net wcf service endpoint

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a set of services in an asp.net service project. I have configured the endpoints for them in web.config.

This is how I setup the endpoints in web.config:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="GeneralBindingConfig" maxBufferSize="524288" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="100000" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="TeamTravel.Cloud.Services.ServiceContracts.AccountServices">
    <endpoint address="/Services" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GeneralBindingConfig" contract="TeamTravel.Cloud.Services.ServiceContracts.Interfaces.IAccountServices" />
  </service>
  <service name="TeamTravel.Cloud.Services.ServiceContracts.JourneyServices">
    <endpoint address="/Services" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GeneralBindingConfig" contract="TeamTravel.Cloud.Services.ServiceContracts.Interfaces.IJourneyServices" />
  </service>
  <service name="TeamTravel.Cloud.Services.ServiceContracts.JourneyTrackerServices">
    <endpoint address="/Services" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GeneralBindingConfig" contract="TeamTravel.Cloud.Services.ServiceContracts.Interfaces.IJourneyTrackerServices" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

In IIS i mounted the website under this binding: www.teamtravel.com
I also added the entry in my hosts file so that I can access the website locally from that url.

So based on the configuration I should be able to access a service like this:

www.teamtravel.com/Services/AccountServices.svc

AccountServices.svc are asp.net wcf services.

But I get redirected to an error path:

http://teamtravel.com/default.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/Services/AccountServices.svc

Comment: I've never heard of an "ASP.NET WCF Service". The two technologies are very different. What is the actual Visual Studio template used to create the project?

Answer (score 1):

When hosting WCF service on IIS, the virtual directory where your service exists defines your service endpoint's address, so you can just leave this property empty:

```
<endpoint address="" ... />
```

And you service will be reachable from `www.teamtravel.com/<YourIISVirtualDirectory>/AccountServices.svc`.

Address property may be used to add endpoints with addresses relative to that address:

```
<endpoint address="anotherEndpoint" .../>
```

so this endpoint will be reachable from `www.teamtravel.com/<YourIISVirtualDirectory>/AccountServices.svc/anotherEndpoint`

For reference, read [Deploying an Internet Information Services-Hosted WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN.